# Format SQL Server Field

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I need a way to remove a comma if that is the 1st character in a field.  For example, the data would be `,Monday` instead of reading just `Monday`  How can I 1st check if the comma is the 1st character in a field, and if it is remove it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN YourCol LIKE ',%' THEN SUBSTRING(YourCol, 2, 8000)
         ELSE YourCol
       END
```

Comment: Seems to be the most readable and efficient way, better than `RIGHT(YourCol,LEN(YourCol)-1)` to get the right part because it doesn't need to calculate the length.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `STUFF`:

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(20) = ',Monday'

SELECT STUFF(LTRIM(@str), 1, CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',', LTRIM(@str)) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0  END, '')
```

If there is a `','` at the beginning of the string (after left trimming is performed) then replace it with `''`, otherwise set `length` parameter of `STUFF` to 0, i.e. do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(50)=',Monday'

SELECT replace(LEFT(@string, 1), ',', '')
       + substring(@string, 2, len(@string))
```